# Getting wrong format on removing and adding new object in given array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, multidimensional-array, arrayobject

I am working in React js using function component. I need to remove an array object corresponding to an index and add new to array object to the same index. Sample of the multidimensional array object is given below. I tried some methods but nothing gives me the right answer. I think problem is clear. Please do ask if there is any doubts.

**original array object**

```
[
    {
        "area": "Zone1",
        "cartamount": "",
        "extra_shippingamount": "",
        "polygon": [
            [
                {
                    "lat": 11.174036305817275,
                    "lng": 76.3754534171875
                },
                {
                    "lat": 10.526644973776667,
                    "lng": 76.6061663078125
                },
                {
                    "lat": 10.75339097376777,
                    "lng": 77.47957939375
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "lat": 11.28179683077826,
                    "lng": 75.89857811201172
                },
                {
                    "lat": 10.774977003245414,
                    "lng": 76.16774315107422
                },
                {
                    "lat": 11.292570666429365,
                    "lng": 76.91481346357422
                }
            ]
        ],
        "shippingamount": ""
    },
    {
        "area": "Zone2",
        "cartamount": "",
        "extra_shippingamount": "",
        "polygon": [
            [
                {
                    "lat": 11.174036305817275,
                    "lng": 76.3754534171875
                },
                {
                    "lat": 10.526644973776667,
                    "lng": 76.6061663078125
                },
                {
                    "lat": 10.75339097376777,
                    "lng": 77.47957939375
                }
            ]
        ],
        "shippingamount": ""
    },
    {
        "area": "Zone3",
        "cartamount": "",
        "extra_shippingamount": "",
        "polygon": [
            [
                {
                    "lat": 10.755303390976334,
                    "lng": 76.4073785765625
                },
                {
                    "lat": 10.182723497824039,
                    "lng": 76.4018854125
                },
                {
                    "lat": 10.150282003909208,
                    "lng": 77.3082574828125
                },
                {
                    "lat": 10.74990667635129,
                    "lng": 77.291777990625
                },
                {
                    "lat": 11.062755098084468,
                    "lng": 77.0445856078125
                }
            ]
        ],
        "shippingamount": ""
    }
]
```

**Edited object array**

```
[{
        "area": "Zone1",
        "cartamount": "",
        "extra_shippingamount": "",
        "polygon": [
            [{
                    "lat": 11.174036305817275,
                    "lng": 76.3754534171875
                },
                {
                    "lat": 10.526644973776667,
                    "lng": 76.6061663078125
                },
                {
                    "lat": 10.75339097376777,
                    "lng": 77.47957939375
                }
            ],
            [{
                    "lat": 9.62536187827369,
                    "lng": 76.88150729970702
                },
                {
                    "lat": 9.023680418742487,
                    "lng": 76.77164401845702
                },
                {
                    "lat": 9.299749165335365,
                    "lng": 78.76737918691406
                }
            ]
        ],
        "shippingamount": ""
    },
    {
        "area": "Zone2",
        "cartamount": "",
        "extra_shippingamount": "",
        "polygon": [
            [{
                    "lat": 11.174036305817275,
                    "lng": 76.3754534171875
                },
                {
                    "lat": 10.526644973776667,
                    "lng": 76.6061663078125
                },
                {
                    "lat": 10.75339097376777,
                    "lng": 77.47957939375
                }
            ]
        ],
        "shippingamount": ""
    },
    {
        "area": "Zone3",
        "cartamount": "",
        "extra_shippingamount": "",
        "polygon": [
            [{
                    "lat": 10.755303390976334,
                    "lng": 76.4073785765625
                },
                {
                    "lat": 10.182723497824039,
                    "lng": 76.4018854125
                },
                {
                    "lat": 10.150282003909208,
                    "lng": 77.3082574828125
                },
                {
                    "lat": 10.74990667635129,
                    "lng": 77.291777990625
                },
                {
                    "lat": 11.062755098084468,
                    "lng": 77.0445856078125
                }
            ]
        ],
        "shippingamount": ""
    }
]
```

[image: orignal array]

[image: sample of edited array]

*The given is the code I tried but it gives wrong format.*

```
 const onEdit = useCallback(() => {

        if (polygonRef.current) {
            const nextPath = polygonRef?.current
                .getPath()
                .getArray()
                .map((latLng: any) => {
                    return { lat: latLng.lat(), lng: latLng.lng() };
                });
            setPath(nextPath);
        //   const  nextPath=[{
        //         "lat": 9.62536187827369,
        //         "lng": 76.88150729970702
        //     },
        //     {
        //         "lat": 9.023680418742487,
        //         "lng": 76.77164401845702
        //     },
        //     {
        //         "lat": 9.299749165335365,
        //         "lng": 78.76737918691406
        //     }]
            let getMapzones = localStorage.getItem("mapZone");
            if (typeof getMapzones == 'string') {
                let localZone = JSON.parse(getMapzones);
                let tempData = localZone?.map((item: any, key: any) => {
                    if (key == coordIndex) {
                        return item?.polygon?.map((el: any, index: any) => {
                            if (index == curIndex) {
                                el = nextPath
                                return el
                            }
                            else {
                              return   el
                            }
                        })

                    }
                    else {
                        return item
                    }


                })
                localStorage.setItem('mapZone', JSON.stringify(tempData))
                
            }
        }
    }, [coordIndex, curIndex])
```

*output of my code*
Lost  the other values (area, cartamount, extra_shippingamount, shippingamount )& other polygon values from the array coresponding to the index. New array object replaces the whole array.

```
[
    [
        [{
                "lat": 9.62536187827369,
                "lng": 76.88150729970702
            },
            {
                "lat": 9.023680418742487,
                "lng": 76.77164401845702
            },
            {
                "lat": 9.299749165335365,
                "lng": 78.76737918691406
            }
        ]
    ],
    {
        "area": "Zone2",
        "cartamount": "",
        "extra_shippingamount": "",
        "polygon": [
            [{
                    "lat": 11.174036305817275,
                    "lng": 76.3754534171875
                },
                {
                    "lat": 10.526644973776667,
                    "lng": 76.6061663078125
                },
                {
                    "lat": 10.75339097376777,
                    "lng": 77.47957939375
                }
            ]
        ],
        "shippingamount": ""
    },
    {
        "area": "Zone3",
        "cartamount": "",
        "extra_shippingamount": "",
        "polygon": [
            [{
                    "lat": 10.755303390976334,
                    "lng": 76.4073785765625
                },
                {
                    "lat": 10.182723497824039,
                    "lng": 76.4018854125
                },
                {
                    "lat": 10.150282003909208,
                    "lng": 77.3082574828125
                },
                {
                    "lat": 10.74990667635129,
                    "lng": 77.291777990625
                },
                {
                    "lat": 11.062755098084468,
                    "lng": 77.0445856078125
                }
            ]
        ],
        "shippingamount": ""
    }
]
```

Comment: I don't see any overt issues with your logic, so it's unclear what isn't working as you'd expect it to. Can you provide the result of your code against the sample input so we can see where it diverges?

Comment: @DrewReese I have updated the post with the result of my code. Can you please check

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try splicing your array instead? There is no need to map the array in that case, because splice will work on your original array. If you are not willing to modify your original array, you can store it in a temporary array and manipulate the temporary one.

`arr.splice(indexToBeManipulated, 1, newValue);`

.splice() takes the first argument as the index that you would want to start making changes from, the second argument if passed as 0 will not remove any elements starting from the indexToBeManipulaed. But in your case, since you would like to remove one value from the respective index, the second argument should be 1, and the third argument can be the new value you would like to append at the indexToBeManipulaed.

Check this link out for a better understanding of .splice() : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Comment: I tried this method . I need to return the whole array object along with the updated value  instead of spliced value.

Comment: One thing you could try to retain the rest of the values of your array and only change the polygon value is this :   newArray = [...oldArray, polygon: {newValues}]. Try this once. It should only replace the polygon object with the new values and retain the rest of the array.